# Get the current epoch in Anchor

Tags: anchor, rust

I'm writing a Solana program in Anchor and want to know what the current Epoch is. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey there with anchor you can use the **solana_program::clock::Clock** struct.

```
pub struct Clock {
    pub slot: Slot,
    pub epoch_start_timestamp: UnixTimestamp,
    pub epoch: Epoch,
    pub leader_schedule_epoch: Epoch,
    pub unix_timestamp: UnixTimestamp,
}
```

You get the current epoch by using :

```
Clock::get()?.epoch;
```